# mysql backup extremely slow after upgrade from 5.6.23 to 5.7.11

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

we were running a mysql instance on amazon-rds. This instance has over 6000 databases which was no problem so far. We also configured a readonly clone that we are using to run the backup from using automysqlbackup to dump all 6000 databases to a folder. Everything went well with 5.6.23 with low cpu usage (10%) on the rds instance. After max 4 hours all databases were dumped.

Then we decided to upgrade to 5.7.11 because of some new features not available in 5.6.x.

After upgrade to 5.7.11 the picture changed completely. Although automysqlbackup calls mysqldump separately for each database after some time the server responds with

`Couldn't execute 'SELECT DISTINCT TABLESPACE_NAME, FILE_NAME, LOGFILE_GROUP_NAME, EXTENT_SIZE, INITIAL_SIZE, ENGINE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.FILES WHERE FILE_TYPE = 'DATAFILE' AND TABLESPACE_NAME IN (SELECT DISTINCT TABLESPACE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('database_0001426')) ORDER BY TABLESPACE_NAME, LOGFILE_GROUP_NAME': Out of memory (Needed 1665336 bytes) (5)`

then

`mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT DISTINCT TABLESPACE_NAME, FILE_NAME, LOGFILE_GROUP_NAME, EXTENT_SIZE, INITIAL_SIZE, ENGINE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.FILES WHERE FILE_TYPE = 'DATAFILE' AND TABLESPACE_NAME IN (SELECT DISTINCT TABLESPACE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('database_0001427')) ORDER BY TABLESPACE_NAME, LOGFILE_GROUP_NAME': Lost connection to MySQL server during query (2013)`

and then many of these:

`mysqldump: Got error: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com' (111) when trying to connect`

When this happens the freeable memory is down to zero (from 7.5 GB) and swap usage is at around 3.5GB

I tried many different parameters like different timeout settings, sql_mode, buffer size, max_user_connections (although there is only one connection...) but nothing really helps. I also created a new read only clone in a different availability zone and allowed public access although the backup is running on a ec2 instance in the same VPN.

automysqlbackup is configured to run mysqldump with the following options:

`mysqldump --user=yanomo --password=x xxxxxxxxxxxxxx --host=xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com --quote-names --opt --ssl --single-transaction --max_allowed_packet=32M --port=3306 --databases database_0001261`

Is there anything I forgot?

Answer (score 0):

Querying **INFORMATION_SCHEMA** tables was always problematic, if you have many databases and tables. And it may really take a lot of memory. Try to free some memory on Linux, if possible. If not, reduce **innodb_buffer_pool_size** or other memory related parameters. Try to disable **performance_schema**, if it is enabled.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change memory on RDS instances unless upgrade to a larger instance. performance_schema was already disabled and reducing the innodb_buffer_pool_size didn't help either. 
With 5.6.x I was able to export the full schema which was compressed >36MB. This is not longer possible with 5.7.11 - it fails after a while exporting <4MB

Comment: I would make a test on other machine to verify, how much memory is needed exactly. If it is really much higher, comparing with 5.6, then I would file a bug. Try also other backup solutions: percona extrabackup, mydumder etc.